# Using Central Limit Theorem to determine number of simulations required

Tags: simulation

I am trying to determine how many simulations are adequate to estimate number of claims in the next twelve months using a homogenous poisson process.

What I did is simulate 1000 times, find the mean and standard deviation of those simulations, and used CLT to find N (5% confidence interval), what I found is a really small number (<1), this can't be possible. How come CLT doesn't work in this case? is it because 1000 is too small?

I simulated 1000 times and I have a vector with 1000 elements. I calculated the average of these elements and the standard deviation, and I used the formula:
(0.05*Average)/(standard deviation/sqrt(n))=1.96 for a 5% CI with 95% probability.

edit: I followed the formula in the photo, when I calculated the standard deviation, it is very large (around 80).[image]

Comment: Your last formula doesn't make sense to me. If you put sample std. dev for the std.dev in the formula, it's wrong, since you normally divide the deviation of a $X$ by $\sqrt{N}$ to get the normalizing constant in this case. Btw, where did you get your formula?

Comment: I tried to follow the follow in the image, didn't really work for me

Comment: Where did you get this formula from? Do you have any references? It seems it plugs in $\alpha$ inside the probability, and $1-\alpha$ outside on the LHS, which doesn't make sense when $\alpha=0$

Comment: this is from my lecture in uni :) when I use the sample deviation, I get a really small number using that formula, I also tried using your formula down below, and I get 4000k which is very large?

Comment: What did you put for $w$ in that formula? There is no large or small, it depends on your $w$ :). What is your sample mean and sample std. deviation?

Comment: my sample mean is 6365 and deviation is 83, I used 0.05 for w to have a 95% CI, and I got 4m as my N

Comment: Well, if you input 0.05 for $w$, it means you want to be 95 % sure that your mean resides in $6365\pm 0.05$, which can be large of course, since your standard deviation is around $80$. don't use $w$ as a probability. Use it for constraining your range, i.e. $[\mu \pm w]$

Comment: Correcting here also: $[\mu \pm w/2]$

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you've made several experiments and got your means as $X_1,X_2,...X_N$. The essence of CLT is approximating *sample mean* as normal, i.e. $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N{X_i}$ is assumed to be normal. And, rest assured that $1000$ is not a small number in this case. So, your estimated sample mean is approximately normally distributed.

If you want to have a [$95 \%$ CI](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) for your estimate, you can just add and subtract $2\sigma_{\bar{X}}$ to your observed mean. Here, if you don't know the true deviation of $X_i$ (if you know it,  $\sigma_{\bar{X}}=\frac{\sigma_{X_i}}{\sqrt{N}}$, you can also estimate it using your sample set.

Your question, "what should $N$ be for 95% CI?", is not complete. For every $N$, you can have a 95 % CI. Of course, for small $N$, it'll be large since you're more uncertain and vice versa. Here, you can adjust $N$ to limit the width of your CI, i.e. what should N be such that my CI has width = $w$? For this, we first calculate the width (for 95 % CI), and that is $4\sigma_{\bar{X}}=4\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}$, and you'll have $N\approx \left(\frac{4\sigma}{w}\right)^2$

Comment: is the sigma in (4σ/w)^2 the sample standard deviation from my 1000 simulations?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding in my first comment, you can plug in the sample standard deviation for $\sigma$, yes. Normally, $\sigma$ is true dev, where $S$ is denoted for sample dev.

Comment: Hi! so I want to compute N so that my range is constrained as 6365±5, i used your formula and got 4200, which seems reasonable. However, i was just wondering, how come in your formula, there's no sample mean and 1.96? i.e. the critical value for 95% probability?

Comment: Btw, my mistake: $\mu \pm w/2$, so N is nearly 1K. Since you have a normal distribution, and know the sample deviation, the width doesn't depend on $\mu$. Please check the link in my answer. And, that $1.96$ is actually embedded in $2\sigma$ in my formula. The number $1.96$ is for std. normal, which has $\sigma=1$, and $2\sigma \approx 1.96$.

Comment: But my sigma is 80 and no where close to 1, does that mean its not normally distributed?

Comment: You're confusing std. normal dist. vs normal dist. $\bar{X}$ is normal while $\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma}$ is std. normal.

Comment: so the correct formula is (4*std)/(w/2) all squared?

Comment: No, the formula is true,  but $w$ is the complete width, i.e $10 \pm 2$ has $w=4$.

Comment: @gunes, excuse my dimness. Is $2\sigma_{\bar X}$ to approximate $\Phi^{-1}(.975) \sigma_{\bar X}$?

Comment: @Student yes. $\Phi(2)\approx 0.975$ (not perfectly equal), this is a common approximation.

Comment: @gunes thank you for confirming. That is interesting because I’d always seen it written to two decimal places. Perhaps a difference of disciplines?

Comment: Most z tables use 4 decimal places. But, it’s because $\pm 2\sigma$ corresponds to 95 % CI for normal data. The right and left ends of it each has 2.5 % of the data, which makes the CDF value at 2 0.975